# Estimate the number of roots of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic with $0 \not = f(0)$. Suppose we have normalized $f$ such that $|f(0)| = 1$. Suppose that $f$ has $n$ roots (including repeated roots) and they are all in $B_{\frac 12}(0)$. Is it possible to estimate $n$ in terms the maximum value of $f$ on the unit circle  !?

Comment: $$f(z)={(z-a)(z-b)\cdots(z-q)\over ab\cdots q}$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, there is no uniform bound on $n$. By estimate, I mean an estimation depending on $f$. such as its maximum on the unit circle.

Comment: [Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula) gives an estimate. Is that good enough for your purposes?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By Jensen's formula, $n\leq \frac{\log M}{\log2}$, where $M = \sup\limits_{\vert z\vert =1}\vert f(z)\vert$. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula